# Centering header image div in whole page / not browser window size

Tags: html, css

I'd like to center my header image to be in the center of the whole page - not the center of the browser window base on what size it is.
Site is www.anathema.me

Here's the css.

```
 #wrapper {
 margin: 0 auto;  
 }

 #header {
 margin: 0 auto;
 background: #FFFFFF;
 text-align: center;
  }

   #header img {
 max-width: 40%;
 height: auto;
  }
```

Comment: Having a hard time finding the answer.. A lot of them just do what I'm trying not to do.

Comment: if in more than 100 answers related to centring you don't find what you need [i didn't count all the related links and external ressource] .. then make you question more clear and share all the needed code within the question ... and show us how you want your header to be centred

Comment: Right now it's being centered based on the window size. The content div is bigger than the window size sometimes and the header will not align with the content div. It just is center aligned with the size of the window.

Comment: you have a fixed width on content so apply the same fixed width on the header or use `min-width: 960px;`